# How to get the value of UTF-8 character

Tags: c, utf-8

I have an utf-8 character in chinese or arabic language. I need to get the value of that UTF-8 character, like getting a value of ASCII character. I need to implement it in "C". Can you please provide your suggestions?

For example:

```
char array[3] = "ab";
int v1,v2;

v1 = array[0];
v2 = array[1];
```

In the above code I will get corresponding ASCII values in v1 and v2. In the same way for UF8 string I need to get the value for each character in a string.

Comment: You probably ought to use a Unicode library for this

Comment: If you have the character you already have the value... What exactly is the Value of a utf-8 char to you?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... what do you have as input, an UTF-8 string? And you want the values of its Unicode codepoints?

Comment: Use [wchar_t](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wchar_t) & related library functions?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I have updated my question.

Comment: Your question is still weak. Are you looking to convert a UTF-8 string into an array of Unicode characters? To convert UTF-8 to UTF-32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the C11 standard version of the C language offers UTF-8 support, so depending on what standard you are targeting, you can use the C11 features (`<uchar.h>`) or rely on a UTF library such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a UTF-8 character. There are Unicode characters and there are encodings for Unicode characters such as UTF-8.

What you probably want is to decode several bytes - encoded in UTF-8 and representing a single Unicode character - into the Unicode code point.

There's lot of C source code for this available in the net. Just google for [UTF-8 decoding C](https://www.google.ch/search?q=utf-8+decoding+c).

**Update:**

What you're obviously looking for is a UTF-8 decoding for more than just one character, namely a function decoding an array of bytes (UTF-8 decoded text) into an array of ints (Unicode code points).

The answer remains the same: use Google. There's lot of C code for it out there.

Comment: You answer appears to re-state the question and tell OP to search on Google. That's rather weak. Why don't you write a real answer, or delete it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There's a lot of confusion about Unicode and encodings, often because technical terms are mixed up and improperly used. My answer tries to help by correcting some of the misuse and better describing what 2vision2 is probably looking for. According to the up-votes others seem to consider this valuable as well.

Comment: Well, I offer a different verdict.

Answer (score 5):

C and C++ model is that the encoding is tied to the locale, so code using that model works for the encoding of the locale, whatever it is.

If you have a locale using UTF8 for the narrow encoding. See `mbtowc()`, `mbrtowc()`, `mbstowcs` and `mbsrtocws()`,they should be pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: Although, depending from the platform, wide characters may actually be UTF-16, which means that you don't get the codepoint number from a single character if it is outside the BMP.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, wide characters encoding can't be UTF-16 in conforming implementations (it can be UCS-2).

Comment: then the state of affairs on Windows is even more messed up than I thought.

Answer (score 4):

With icu, you can skip through utf8 characters with [U8_NEXT](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utf8_8h.html#a57f3e5429ae4edb27a42367c627aa482)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unicode/utf.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char s[] = "日本語";

    UChar32 c;
    int32_t k;
    int32_t len = strlen(s);

    for (k = 0; k < len;) {
        U8_NEXT(s, k, len, c);
        printf("%d - %x\n", k, c);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

To compile with `gcc utf.c -o utf $(icu-config --ldflags --ldflags-icuio)`

The index `k` here indicates the starting offset of the encoding of your `j`th character. And `c` contains the unicode value (32 bits) of the character.

Comment: What does the 9 represent?  `strlen(s)`?

Comment: This is the hardcoded length of the string. You're right, that's not very clean, only a quick example. Here is a cleaner version.